# Adding string to the end of each group's last sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to add string, in this case *"<endofsentence>"* after each group/id's last sentence.

To be precise, what I have now is df2 and i'm trying to get df3 with the following sample code:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
                   'text':['sentence1','sentence2','sentence3','sentence1','sentence2','sentence3','sentence1','sentence2','sentence3'],
                   'time':[1.1234,2.3456,3.4567,0.1234,3.3634,5.5673,2.0123,2.4354,4.3454]})
[Output]:
    id  text    time
0   1   sentence1   1.1234
1   1   sentence2   2.3456
2   1   sentence3   3.4567
3   2   sentence1   0.1234
4   2   sentence2   3.3634
5   2   sentence3   5.5673
6   3   sentence1   2.0123
7   3   sentence2   2.4354
8   3   sentence3   4.3454

df3=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
                   'text':['sentence1','sentence2','sentence3<endofsentence>','sentence1','sentence2','sentence3<endofsentence>','sentence1','sentence2','sentence3<endofsentence>'],
                   'time':[1.1234,2.3456,3.4567,0.1234,3.3634,5.5673,2.0123,2.4354,4.3454]})
[Output]:
    id  text                        time
0   1   sentence1                   1.1234
1   1   sentence2                   2.3456
2   1   sentence3<endofsentence>    3.4567
3   2   sentence1                   0.1234
4   2   sentence2                   3.3634
5   2   sentence3<endofsentence>    5.5673
6   3   sentence1                   2.0123
7   3   sentence2                   2.4354
8   3   sentence3<endofsentence>    4.3454
```

**Note**: `sentence1, sentence2, sentence3` are random sentences that are unique for each group

My current solution isn't the most elegant but it gets the job done but was wondering if there is a more efficient or even smarter way to go about this that will scale well even with millions of records. Would appreciate any help I can get!

Current Solution:

```
df_temp = df2.groupby('id')[['time']].agg(np.max).reset_index().rename(columns={'time':'max_time'})
df4 = df2.join(df_temp.set_index('id'), on='id')
df4.loc[df4['time'] == df4['max_time'], ['text']] = df4.text + "<endofsentence>"

[Output]:
    id  text                        time    max_time
0   1   sentence1                   1.1234  3.4567
1   1   sentence2                   2.3456  3.4567
2   1   sentence3<endofsentence>    3.4567  3.4567
3   2   sentence1                   0.1234  5.5673
4   2   sentence2                   3.3634  5.5673
5   2   sentence3<endofsentence>    5.5673  5.5673
6   3   sentence1                   2.0123  4.3454
7   3   sentence2                   2.4354  4.3454
8   3   sentence3<endofsentence>    4.3454  4.3454
```

Comment: What is your current solution? It isn't shown in your example.

Comment: @Tim Just added it

Comment: `df2 = df2 .replace( 'sentence3', 'sentence3<endofsentence>' )`
`print( df2 )`

Comment: @Doyousketch2 but sentence3 is unique for each id, so I don't think I can do as u suggested unless i'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see what you're saying.  This seems to do:

```py
ids = df2 .id
unequal = ids .index[ ids .shift(-1) != ids ]
df2 .text .loc[ unequal ] += '<endofsentence>'

print( df2 )
```

```
  id                      text    time
0   1                 sentence1  1.1234
1   1                 sentence2  2.3456
2   1  sentence3<endofsentence>  3.4567
3   2                 sentence1  0.1234
4   2                 sentence2  3.3634
5   2  sentence3<endofsentence>  5.5673
6   3                 sentence1  2.0123
7   3                 sentence2  2.4354
8   3  sentence3<endofsentence>  4.3454
```

Comment: Well, your `max_time` column was added after the original question.  I didn't see that 'till just now.  You can add that back in.  I think this solves what you were setting out to do.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! Thank you!